# Infinite Road Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on Unity for a month. I am new on Unity and C#, before Unity I worked other game engines. Whatever I am working on infinite run game, I wrote random road generator. Road generator is working well but I have problem about updating road. I can update road manualy like this. How can I update it automaticly?

```
void Update()
{
     if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) UpdateRoad();
}
```

My UpdateRoad method adding road like this(I am using object pooling).
[image]
I want to update after Link Road, OnExitTrigger or something I dont know. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: 3D i am using z position

Comment: I know nothing about unity, but it sounds like a good candidate for an event subscription. If there's some event that gets triggered as the user travels the road, you could call UpdateRoad() there (possibly based on some other state variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement Object Pooling.

I would suggest making your Design of Objects first so you can test. Or if not use, the stock Blocks Primitive of Unity3D as your Prefabs. I hope you already know prefabs. It is a major key for making infinite runner. Actually a main core for making any kinds of game.

Prefabs is an Object File where you can Instantiate it in a location. So lets say you will generate a Flat walkable, then Generate a Pit. You would probably want to stack them together.

Now Generating them is easy. You would not like to go in an Update? Approach because most likely you're not going to update, but you're going to further stack what is going on ahead, based on your game logic.

To further Understand this, Unity3D already made a project or Fully Detailed tutorial. It maybe made in 2D but it is going to be the same, if you're going to change the Collider2D to Collider <- this is important in your case.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/infinite-runner

**Update**

You would need to create an Object, that is invisible. Meaning a Trigger.
Then on Trigger call your method UpdateRoad();

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers

Detailed Videos about Trigger.

Comment: I am using object pool already. My codes are working well but how can i update road? I thought with OnTriggerExit but I dont know is this best way?

Comment: For me to answer your question. What exactly do you want to update in the Road? It's component or Replace the Object itself? If Components. What specific components do you want to update so I can add it.

Comment: I want to when player passed LinkRoad prefab(you can see image on my post) UpdateRoad method should work for one time. for example if(player.position.z > linkprefab.position.z) UpdateRoad();

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your needs correctly, you could create Empty Object name it SpawnPoint, set position for Spawn Point as you need (out of the camera view) and then Instanciate random prefabs of road. Concerning On TriggerExit - it could be used to destroy "old piece of road". But to have it working properly, dont forget to set collider and rigitbody to your objects. Dont add collider2D or Rigitbody2d, add and use Box Collider and Rigitbody components